# Access Item in Nested Structure in C

Tags: c

I try to access "next" in another structure, but failed although i have tried many ways.

Here is the nested structure:

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

typedef struct {
  char *key;
  char *value;
  struct list_head list;
}dict_entry;
```

I want to access "next". I initialize a new dict_entry.

```
dict_entry *d;
while(d->list->next!=NULL){}
```

but it was wrong. Could anyone give me a way to access that "next"? 
Note: i could not change the structure.

Comment: _If_ the answers below do not solve your problem, I'd be thinking  macro clashes before "compiler errors". `list` _might_ have been defined as a macro in some header. To investigate, you can try undefining, or better look at the preprocessed output.

Answer (score 1):

`list` is not declared as a pointer, so you don't use the `->` operator to get its members, you use the `.` operator:

```
while (d->list.next != NULL) {
}
```

---

A different fix:

```
typedef struct {
  char *key;
  char *value;
  struct list_head *list;
}dict_entry;
```

This way, your original code attempting to refer to `next` would compile.

Comment: OP, have you initialized `d`? The statement `dict_entry *d;` leaves `d` null.

Answer (score 1):

In your definition, you are defining `list` to be an object as below

```
typedef struct {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct list_head list; // This is an object
}dict_entry;
```

Hence, you will de-reference `next` through the `.` operator as `d->list.next`. The first level of de-referencing i.e. `d->list` requires `->` operator as `d` is defined to be a pointer. For `next`, since `list` is an object and **not** a pointer, you would have to use `.` operator.